# Changing a transactional email based on total spend?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders

I'd like customers who spend more than $50 to get an additional sentence in their confirmation email. So **if ordervalue <= 50**, I guess.

- Is this possible?
- Or can an extension do it?
- I can't seem to find anything online as the phrasing is awkward. Any
  help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the code below in the email template which is located at *app/locale/[language code]/emails/sales*, or change the template in the backend under *System > Transactional Emails*

```
 {{if order.getBaseGrandTotal() >=50}}
 // add your text
 {{/if}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution will probably be to embed a block into the e-mail so you can perform the logic in a custom template.

```
{{block type="core/template" area="frontend" template="some_custom_template_file.phtml" order=$order}}
```

Then in the template you can do something like:

```
<?php if ($order->getGrandTotal() >= 50) : ?>
    Your custom message goes here.
<?php endif; ?>
```